# how to save an image file in R with pca3d package

Tags: r, tiff, pca

I want to save a tiff image of a pca graphic from `pca3d` package in R, I've tried with the next code but in the out I just get a white image, the console returns NULL Device. Does somebody why that happen?

```
tiff("pca.tiff")
pca2d(pca, group=matrix.grupos[,1], show.scale=TRUE, show.centroids=TRUE, 
      show.group.labels=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

pca is my microarray data but you can take the "metabo" data example from the package, so the code would be like this:

```
library(pca3d)
data(metabo)
pca <- prcomp(metabo[,-1], scale.= TRUE)

tiff("pca.tiff")
pca2d(pca, group= metabo[,1])
dev.off()
```

Comment: We don't have your variables `pca` or `matrix.grupos` so we would just be guessing. Can you provide these variables? Otherwise this question will be closed for asking debugging help without providing a reproducible example.

Comment: @AngelRuvalcaba, I tried your code and I was able to save the image without any problems. Did you check the working directory? Maybe the Sys.info() could be useful.

Comment: yes as you said, with metabo data works, I checked the wd but the image has nothing, just a white image. Now I tried again and finally works, maybe its a problem related to the library pca3d